# Not all Facebook friends are being returned

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm using the Facebook API in order to return the user's friends. However, when i run the the code, it returns only two users and this two users i'm using through out the testing and they are the only ones who gave permission for the app. However, all of my hundreds of users do no appear (are not returned in the results). Here is what i'm doing:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"RESULT %@", result); 
}];
```

This is how i'm returning the list of friends. is there anything wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Facebook API is only returning the friends that are using your app.

From the documentation:
`This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.`

Maybe you can use the invitable friends list that is now offered...

Comment: Thank you @robert ! I was looking at the online reference for this method and it wasn't showing much information other than "it returns user's friends" please can you send me the link of where you got this line of info? Thanks!

Comment: here it is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends